# Unable to add a table and list of links on the same line/Row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an asp.net mvc core web application which uses bootstrap. now i want to show a three links + a table on the same row, here is my code:-

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="service_details_left">
        <h3>Services</h3>
        <div class="nav nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist"
             aria-orientation="vertical">
            <a class=" active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home"
               role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Ocean Freight</a>
            <a class="" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile"
               role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Land Transport</a>
            <a class="" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages"
               role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Air Freight</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-hover col-lg-8 col-md-8">
    <thead>
        <tr>
// table code goes here
```

but i am getting the links and the table of separate lines, as follow:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
div.col-lg-4.col-md-4 { display: inline }
table.table.table-hover.col-lg-8.col-md-8 {display: inline-table }
</style>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26185789)